# how to get data in webservices data from webservices other?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, webmethod

I have a web service that returns bytes as part of XML data. I pass this byte data with the "DoPost" method to another web service address to return XML format. But from the second web service, I do not know how to get value when it's passed.

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EPCISDocumentType));
    ObjectEventType objectEventType = new ObjectEventType();
    EPCISDocumentType epcisDoc = new EPCISDocumentType();
    epcisDoc = (EPCISDocumentType)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(fileStream);

    objectEventType.epcList = epcList.ToArray();
    objectEventType.eventTime = DateTime.Now;
    objectEventType.eventTimeZoneOffset = DateTime.Now.ToString("zzz");
    ReadPointType readPointType = new ReadPointType();
    readPointType.id = locationMasterItems.ReadPoint;
    objectEventType.readPoint = readPointType;
    BusinessLocationType businessLocationType = new BusinessLocationType();
    businessLocationType.id = locationMasterItems.BusinessLocation;
    objectEventType.bizLocation = businessLocationType;

    epcisDoc.EPCISBody = new EPCISBodyType();
    epcisDoc.EPCISBody.EventList = new object[1];
    epcisDoc.EPCISBody.EventList[0] = objectEventType;

    byte[] bsRequest = EpcSerializer.ToEPCISDocumentTypeBytes(epcisDoc);
    HttpCli client = new HttpCli();
    client.Open("http://localhost:5003/WebService.asmx/Getdata");
    client.DoPost(bsRequest, "text/xml; charset=utf-8", null, 60000);

    if (client.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        throw new Exception("error " + client.StatusCode + " ");
    }
}
```

and webservices 2

```
[WebMethod]
public void Getdata() {
    string HostURI = "http://localhost:49227/RFIDWebService.asmx";
    getByte(HostURI);
}

[WebMethod]
private byte[] getByte(string URL) 
{
    string s;
    HttpWebRequest wrGETURL = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL); 
    System.Net.HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)wrGETURL.GetResponse();
    wrGETURL.Method = "GET";
    wrGETURL.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
    string ct = webresponse.ContentType;
    Stream objStream = webresponse.GetResponseStream();

    BinaryReader breader = new BinaryReader(objStream); 
    byte[] buffer = breader .ReadBytes((int)webresponse.ContentLength);
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(buffer))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(ms))
    {
        s = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    return buffer; 
}
```

How to get data variable "bsRequest" from webservice  to webservice 2 and return bsRequest to XML?

Comment: why Getdata() returns void instead of sth?